# ItextSharp no me reconoce los acentos

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itextsharp

Estoy realizando un reporte con la libreria itextsharp y con vb.net. Todo ha ido bien salvo que cuando toca imprimir una palabra con acento no la reconoce y pone otros simbolos. Alguien me podria decir como solucionar este problemita??. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu pregunta con lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5044017/4092887) o busca en Google _itextsharp vb special characters_.

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta @antonio. Estoy cubriendo el tema principal, asumiendo que estás teniendo problemas para visualizar caracteres Unicode. Pero si se debe a otro tema, deberías mostrar tu código y el texto tal cual lo estás visualizando.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder visualizar caracteres Unicode en iTextSharp correctamente, se debe agregar una fuente que soporte los *code points* que se están utilizando.

El punto principal consta en especificar `IDENTITY-H`, que provee soporte Unicode para una fuente que lo permita.

Por ejemplo, para la fuente Arial (que se encuentra en la carpeta de fuentes de Windows):

```
Dim arial As BaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
fuente = New Font(arial, 12)
```

Y luego, se puede utilizar en un párrafo:

```
document.Add(New Paragraph("¡Muchísimas felicidades y buen fin de año!", fuente))
```